# Functions exist but not found in the Revit API documentation

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a simple question. In the Revit API metadata, some functions such as get_parameter(...) or get_geometry(...) in element class. However, they are not displayed in the [documentation](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/671c33f6-169b-17ca-583b-42f9df50ace5.htm).

I expect to find all properties and functions in the docs. If not, How am I supposed to know they exist?

Comment: It is not really that uncommon for the documentation and API to differ slightly, or in some cases, a lot. This may be due to version missmatches, or just that developers forget to update the documentation. There can also be methods and behavior intentionally left undocumented, and they may be removed or change behavior in future versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the `get_` prefix is automatically generated by .NET to enable a C# client to pass in arguments to a property call. Please read The Building Coder article explanining [what is get_Parameter and get_Geometry](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2023/03/uv-emergence-fuzz-and-the-get_-prefix.html#5).